# Ubuntu 16.04 clearing my browser cache and cookies after shutdown

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, shutdown, session, cache

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and I am using Chrome as my default browser. I had set my site preferences and other details etc. in the browser so that every time I visit a particular website I don't have to login again. It all works fine till I am active in my OS session but once I restart my system, those all browser preferences are gone.

Is Ubuntu deleting my browser cache and cookies and site preferences at the time of shutdown. How do I revert it back?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue for about 2 months

Comment: See if it helps: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/10686330?hl=en#zippy=%2Clinux